# Swiping of Multiple Views in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have three ViewControllers. I want to swipe the view controllers one by one which is similar to UIPageViewController. I searched for that in so many tutorials I did not find that.

Iam new to Objective-c.

Comment: r u tried app coda tutorial

Comment: Ya i tried in that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) will help you get started, it has multiple views and a persistent view as well. It also has the [source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/PageApp.zip), so you can dive into the code if you don't want to read the tutorial.

If you don't want to use `UIPageViewController` take the `UICollectionView` approach to simplify things.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363197/uicollectionview-horizontal-paging-with-3-items) for an example.

Comment: Iam not asking the UIPageviecontroller.Swiping of the view same as the Pageview...

Comment: So please explain your requirements clearly and I can edit the answer. So you have multiple views that you want to swipe horizontally on the screen, without using UIPageViewController?

Comment: I would suggest you use a collection view with horizontal flow layout. This way you don't have to deal with scrolling and other gestures. Updated the answer