# How to make paging animation for a collectionView cell scrolling to center?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swift 3 to write an app which has a `UIViewController` looks like the following picture. It contains a horizontal-scrollable `collectionView` (the blue block) on the top, and its functionality is to  switch between different labels(first, prev, current, next, last...etc, the total amount of labels are not fixed). What I need to achieve is that on scrolling (or panning) the collection view, the **'NEXT'** or **'PREV'** should move (and anchor automatically) to the center with velocity similar to paging animation. How could I achieve this? Currently I use the `Paging Enabled` attribute of the `scrollView`, however this only work when there is one label in the window.

Similar features may look like the middle "albums" section of iTunes app, which the collectionView cell would scroll to some pre-defined point automatically with some animation once it detects any swipe/pan gesture.

[image]

Comment: do you select cell using tap or sliding?

Comment: It's designed to be switchable when slide, however if it could be tapped to select, then it would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Raheel's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23386007/4963585), I finally find a way for a desirable scroll effect. Some key functions are listed as follow in swift:

1. First, disable `Paging Enabled` attribute of the `scrollView`
2. Define `setIdentityLayout()` and `setNonIdentityLayout()` which defines the layouts of both selected / non-selected cell (for example, `MyCollectionViewCell` in this case)
3. Define some related properties such as:

   ```
   lazy var COLLECTION_VIEW_WIDTH: CGFloat = {
       return CGFloat(self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 2)
   }()

   fileprivate let TRANSFORM_CELL_VALUE = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1) // Or define other transform effects here
   fileprivate let ANIMATION_SPEED = 0.2
   ```
4. implement the following key methods for `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

   ```
   func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       // Do tableView data refresh according to the corresponding pages here
   }

   func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

       // Scroll to corresponding position
       let pageWidth: Float = Float(COLLECTION_VIEW_WIDTH)  // width + space
       let currentOffset: Float = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
       let targetOffset: Float = Float(targetContentOffset.pointee.x)
       var newTargetOffset: Float = 0

       if targetOffset > currentOffset {
           newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
       }
       else {
           newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
       }
       if newTargetOffset < 0 {
           newTargetOffset = 0
       }
       else if (newTargetOffset > Float(scrollView.contentSize.width)){
           newTargetOffset = Float(Float(scrollView.contentSize.width))
       }

       targetContentOffset.pointee.x = CGFloat(currentOffset)
       scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(newTargetOffset), y: scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: true)

       // Set transforms
       let identityIndex: Int = Int(newTargetOffset / pageWidth)

       var cell = delegate!.roomCollections.cellForItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: identityIndex, section: 0)) as? MyCollectionViewCell

       UIView.animate(withDuration: ANIMATION_SPEED, animations: {
           cell?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
           cell?.setIdentityLayout()
       })

       // right cell
       cell = delegate!.roomCollections.cellForItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: identityIndex + 1, section: 0)) as? MyCollectionViewCell

       UIView.animate(withDuration: ANIMATION_SPEED, animations: {
           cell?.transform = self.TRANSFORM_CELL_VALUE
           cell?.setNonIdentityLayout()
       })

       // left cell, which is not necessary at index 0
       if (identityIndex != 0) { 
           cell = delegate!.roomCollections.cellForItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: identityIndex - 1, section: 0)) as? MyCollectionViewCell
           UIView.animate(withDuration: ANIMATION_SPEED, animations: {
               cell?.transform = self.TRANSFORM_CELL_VALUE
               cell?.setNonIdentityLayout()
           })
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finally, define initial layout in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`:

   ```
   if (indexPath.row == 0 && /* other first item selected condition */) {
       cell.setIdentityLayout()
   } else {
       cell.transform = TRANSFORM_CELL_VALUE 
       cell.setNonIdentityLayout()
   }
   ```

To add touch scroll effect, simply add target to each collection views, and do similar calculation which changes the contentOffSet of the `scrollView`, which is omitted here because this feature is simpler and not the primary question.

Answer (score 1):

according to your comment if you want to do the Tap to select thing there are 2 things you need to do

1- Disable Collection View Scrolling in viewDidLoad

```
collectionView.isScrollingEnabled = false
```

2- Display Selected Cell in Center , add this in your didSelectItemAtIndexPath method

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

collection.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizantally)

let cell  = collectionView.cellForItem(at : indexPath) as! YourCollectionViewCellClass
cell.titleLable.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize : 20)
}
```