# UICollectionView Paging - How to page ,e.g., 3 at a time?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this. The best answer I could find is this one:

[UICollectionView horizontal paging with 3 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363197/uicollectionview-horizontal-paging-with-3-items)

However, there are a few issues with it. I am not trying to do exactly what he is doing. Instead I want 3 cells on screen, evenly spaced vertically and horizontally. When I swipe left, I want to see the next 3 cells with the same layout, and so forth. (So, horizontal scrolling only.)

Simply enabling paging leads to the cells not being centered.

I'm aware I can subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but I'm looking for a simpler solution. Enabling paging almost gets what I want, but not quite. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you space out your cells correctly (3 in visible collection view with correct spacing), and enable paging it should work correctly.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'space out your cells correctly'?